# Is it possible to get a continous power with a constant current demand from a battery

Tags: power, batteries, discharge

So lets suppose I have to design a battery which has a continous power rating , if my load draws constant current ofcourse the battery will discharge and the SOC drops and so does the voltage. How in this case would my battery provide a continous power ? draw more current ?

```
continuous_power = (nominal voltage - DCR*continuous_current)*continuous_current
```

but this nominal voltage would not be available for the full depth of discharge and the power the battery can provide will drop if the load draws constant current.Please correct me if any one my concept or statements is wrong

Comment: what is the word 'continuous' adding to your definition? From the definitions of voltage, current and power, it's obvious that constant current * non constant voltage is non constant power. Does tyhe load require constant power? Does it draw constant current? What voltage does it require? Do you have a DC to DC converter between your battery and load?

Comment: What do you mean by "a battery which has a continous power rating", does it need to deliver the same amount of power? Does the power dissipated in the battery (due to series resitance) need to be constant? As Power = Voltage * Current then obviously if power needs to be kept constant then Voltage and current must **both** change.

Comment: "continous" in my definition would depend on the "continous current" the battery could provide which we can draw from the battery continously without damaging the battery , so lets say if my load requires 90Watts of power constantly and for that amount of power I am already at my "continous current" limit lets say 9Amps then my limitation is that I cannot draw more current as I would risk damaging my battery. In this case the voltage and power would certainly drop ?

Comment: *if my load requires 90Watts of power constantly and for that amount of power I am already at my "continous current" limit* I would consider that **bad design**. You should not operate your battery near its limit. Doing that anyway is asking for trouble. *In this case the voltage and power would certainly drop ?* That is irrelevant from the battery's perspective. The **load** should not draw more current than the battery can safely provide. If that means less power must be drawn from the battery then that is the case.

Comment: @Novice_Developer I think you are seriously confused. You can design a circuit to limit the current a battery provides. But the approach then is to adjust the voltage seen by the load until the load only accepts that limit of current. If you were to make a dead short with copper wire as a load, the circuit would still limit the current by reducing the voltage down very, very low so that the copper wire would only allow that limited current. This is done by using a small amount of voltage "overhead" needed to monitor the current the load is passing.

Comment: @Novice_Developer If the circuit is a linear circuit that monitors the current and adjusts the output voltage, then the power consumed would be also limited and fixed, so long as the battery voltage itself remains the same. However, the battery voltage will, over time, also decline. So the power, under current limit with a linear circuit, would similarly decline as the available battery energy declines and the battery voltage declines. If you are talking about an active circuit like an SMPS, you already have an answer here. But I don't think you are thinking that way. But maybe I'm confused.

Comment: "so lets say if my load requires 90Watts of power constantly and for that amount of power I am already at my "continous current" limit" - then you're screwed. What about that isn't obvious?

Answer (score 1):

Since the power is the product of voltage and current, and the latter is dependent on the load (assuming it does not exceed the maxium current the source can deliver), I guess you should look at it from the load side instead the source one. An almost perfect example of constant power load is a SMPS (Switch mode power supply), which essentially transfer power from its input to the output with a given loss.

Normally a power supply is rated for a maximum output power, meaning that as long as its output voltage-current product and its maximum output current are kept under the rated values, it should be fully operational. However, sometimes the load may draw too much current way above the specs, meaning that the output voltage of the power supply has to drop in order to maintain the maximum output power.

For a highly resistive or capacitive load, the maximum power would be given by:

**Resistive**

\$P_{max}= (V_{supply} - V_{drop\_max}) \cdot I_{load} \$

**Capacitive**

\$P_{max}= \frac{C(V_{supply}^2 - V_{min}^2)}{2t}\$ where \$V_{min} = V_{supply} - V_{drop\_max}\$

Comment: Thats my question actually I have a current limit for my "continous current" above which I might risk damaginf my battery , If my load draws the maximum current allowed (which is this continous current limit) and then I cannot draw more current , the only thing which would alter my power rating would be the voltage across the battery , in short I am trying to calculate the maximum power my cell could provide for my maximum continous current limit and minimum voltage cut-off

Comment: I am not so sure I understood you completely. You have a source supplying a load, which is drawing a constant current (max). At this point, any extra current drawn will lead to a voltage drop in order to keep a contant power. The maximum deliverable power will depend on whether the voltage drop is so large to point of driving the circuitry out of operation (undervoltage). This is very much dependent on the actual circuit and load you have.

Comment: @Novice_Developer Why not just calculate: (minimum voltage cutoff) x (maximum continuous current)?